# Dashboard Widgets - Add Admin Page With Same Functionality

Tags: widgets, wp-admin, dashboard

I have a plugin that has its own dashboard with basically quick-views of relevant data and I wanted to know if there was an "easy" way to mimic the functionality of the admin dashboard where you can move/minimize/maximize the widgets?

UPDATE:
I am assuming I would have to add metaboxes similar to when you add metaboxes to a custom post type...is this the direction I should go in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess "easy" is a relative term. Yes, you can create your own.

For adding an admin page there are a glut of tutorials out there. This one works (and has some other info you might need) http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/08/ten-things-every-wordpress-plugin-developer-should-know/. Search for "*Add Your Own Settings Page or Admin Menu*" on the page.

jQuery UI is loaded in the WordPress admin. You can use http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets as a starting guide for how to make the dragging/sorting/collapsing happen.

Then, when someone moves or collapses a panel, you'll need to store that change in the database and read it the next time the page loads to reload the configuration.

---

**EDIT**

Try to reverse engineer the actual WP dashboard code first and you may indeed get a lot of the functionality for free.

`/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php` has the widget code (or view source on the dashboard and go from there). Also code for saving/loading settings.

`wp-admin/js/common.js` has the javascript that enables the widget behavior.

The jQuery.UI stuff isn't autoloaded by default so you'll need to wp_enqueue_script what you need.

**Alternatively**
You can skip making your own and simply add custom widgets to the default dashboard. http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API

Comment: Thanks so much for the kickstart.  This will get me on my way.  I figured there wasn't an API I could tap into, but doesn't hurt to ask.  The jQuery UI will get me there...just a lot of manual coding.  Thanks again!

Comment: There is the WP Settings API but it doesn't offer the portlets stuff out of the box. http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API You may be able to dig around in the code that drives the main WP dashboard and take what you need.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at that.  Thanks for the added info.  If I could double-bump up the answer, I would. :-)